# How to make custom template for validation rule's default tooltip?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, controltemplate

How can I make a custom template for the default tooltip which applies automatically to the control, when using the validation rule? and also is there a way to change the duration of this tooltip?

I mean this tooltip:

[image: TextBox in error state with red border and default error tooltip]

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <!--Validation Template-->
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyErrorTemplate">
      <Border BorderBrush="#e92539" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10">
         <Grid>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
         </Grid>
      </Border>
   </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

```
<TextBox FontSize="13" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource MyErrorTemplate}"
         AcceptsReturn="False" Panel.ZIndex="3" x:Name="txtName"
         Style="{StaticResource MyTextBox}" Grid.Row="2">
   <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding Path="txtName" Mode="TwoWay"
               UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
               ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
         <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <local:ValidateTextBox/>
         </Binding.ValidationRules>
      </Binding>
   </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

C#:

```
class ValidateTextBox : ValidationRule
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"[\\/:*?""<>|]");

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string txtNameText = value as string;
        if (regex.IsMatch(txtNameText))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "A file name can't contain any of the following characters:\n \\ / : * ? \" < > |");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adapt your `TextBox` style or create a new one that it sets the `ToolTip` to the current error.

- The first setter sets your custom `ToolTip` template.
- The second setter uses the [`ToolTipService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice?view=net-5.0) to set the attached property [`ShowDuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.showduration?view=net-5.0), which determines how long the tool tip should be shown. There are other useful properties to explore.
- The `Trigger` using the attached property `Validation.HasError` applies the tooltip only if there is an error. This allows you to specify a default tooltip in a different setter.
- Since a `ToolTip` is not part of the same visual tree as its associated control, you have to use a binding to its `PlacementTarget` (the `TextBox)` where the validation errors are attached.

```
<Style x:Key="MyTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
   <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MyErrorTemplate}"/>
   <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="5000"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ToolTip Template="{StaticResource ToolTipTemplate}"
                        Content="{Binding PlacementTarget.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You have to adapt your tooltip control template to bind the `Text` of the `TextBlock` to the `Content` property of the templated parent (the `ToolTip`). This can be done with a `TemplateBinding`.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ToolTipTemplate" TargetType="ToolTip">
   <Grid MaxWidth="400">
      <Border Margin="0,0,35,35"
              Background="#212529"
              BorderBrush="#6C757D"
              BorderThickness="1.7"
              CornerRadius="5">
         <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="Black"
                              Direction="310"
                              ShadowDepth="14"
                              BlurRadius="34"
                              Opacity="0.3"/>
         </Border.Effect>
         <TextBlock Margin="7"
                    Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Foreground="#ADB5BD">
         </TextBlock>
      </Border>
   </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Remove the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` from your `TextBox`, as it is already contained in the style.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now when I hover the mouse on the textbox, the tooltip content is empty

Comment: And also when the textbox is empty and doesn't have any error, it still shows the tooltip on the mouse hover

Comment: @SMH It works for me as expected. Try to test this in an empty solution or without any other styles or modifications applied. There might be other styles or propeties set that cause the issue.

Comment: Yes it's working fine now, sorry that was my fault, I forgot to remove the tooltip that I've added to the textbox itself.